# C program freezes for word lengths greater than 6

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm working through the first chapter of K&R and came to the exercise where you're supposed to create a histogram of word lengths for some input. I started by trying to use a while loop to create an array of zeros as long as the longest word, but inputs with words longer than six characters cause the program to freeze. I'm less interested in just a solution than I am in knowing the cause.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int c, i, l, max;
int length[max];

l = max = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n'){
            ++l;
            if(l > max)
               max = l;
             else
                 ;
             }
        else
            l = 0;
        }
    for(i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        length[i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < max; ++i)    
        printf("\n%d", length[i]);
        putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: How this even compiled? The size of the array is uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` is uninitialized when `length[max]` is defined. Essentially, you're using unallocated memory.

Comment: ok, so I initialized length[max] after the loop that defines max and it works perfectly. Does that imply that after 6 characters the program was trying to eat into some memory that it wasn't allowed or what?

Comment: @Fittesbane - I guess, but it's always hard to tell when you have buffer overruns.